# How do I know what python scripts are running in Windows?

Tags: python, windows

As I mentioned above, is there a way to find out what python scripts are running in Windows?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? Do you mean what Python interpreter is associated with .py files? Or do you mean what Python libraries are active in your current Python installation? Or do you mean what script file is currently being ran by the interpreter?

Comment: It looks like he is trying to ask which scripts are currently being run by the interpreter.

Comment: I agree that he is asking which scripts are being run.  This seems like a legitimate question, since Windows Task Manager calls everything "python.exe". (Up-vote)

Comment: @Michael,@Zonda333 thats what i meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have PowerShell installed, you can get that information by using Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) and some scripting...

Open the PowerShell and use these two lines, it should could you started:

```
> $pys = get-wmiobject Win32_process -filter "Name='python.exe'"
> $pys.CommandLine
```

This will show you the command line arguments used to start the python process, which should contain the name of the main script file ran by Python. For a test program I have, it displays the following:

```
"C:\Python27\python.exe" "D:\Projects\wait.py"
```

In case you have multiple scripts running, the var `$pys` will be an array, so to access it you'll have to access the individual elements like so:

```
> $pys[0].CommandLine
```

**EDIT:** Or you could do it all in one single line, again in PowerShell:

```
 > get-wmiobject Win32_process -filter "Name='python.exe'" | foreach -process {$_.CommandLine}
```

I hope you get the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

> **This is what you need**

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", "get-wmiobject Win32_process -filter \"Name='python.exe'\"| foreach -process {$_.CommandLine}"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
service = "file.py"
if service in str(out):
   print('Service Is Running')
```